# Click on a link-botton in a web page and download-save csv file using vba

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I have been trying all different approach to get the table/data from **[this page](http://www.bmreports.com/bsp/BMRSSystemData.php?pT=DDAD&zT=N&dT=NRT)** using `Excel VBA` but without any result.
My last attempt is, using `Excel VBA`, to open the web page click on `CSV` and save the file in a given location.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: what about `Data>Get External Data>From Web`. This is the menu command on XL2010 (and probably 2007, or close to it.) If you have 2003 it's there, just maybe under a different menu bar sequence.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman I tried all options "get external data" was my first one but it feiled :(

Comment: is the website a private vendor? that requires a pwd? scour google for automating IE with VBA. There's loads of info... perhaps you can find your solution.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman no Pass required on the same web for other type of data I managed to used "get External Data" but on this one everything fails. Thanks anyway

Comment: Are you able to manually download CSV file? The URL you provide yields an error message when I try to access the CSV button, "No Data to Display" and "There was an error calling the Web Service".

Comment: @DavidZemens Dthe web is : http://www.bmreports.com/bsp/BMRSSystemData.php?pT=DDAD&zT=N&dT=NRT I manage to download the file manually but I do not know how to do it programmatically :(

Comment: @DavidZemens which browser are you using? it works fine with internet explorer, it might create problems with chrome. Thanks

Comment: ahhh yes I'm using Chrome. Didn't even think to check in IE.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another example. This should get you as far as the "Save" dialog box.

```
Sub AnotherExample()
Dim URL As String
Dim ieApp As Object
Dim ieDoc As Object
Dim ieForm As Object
Dim ieObj As Object
Dim objColl As Collection

URL = "http://www.bmreports.com/bsp/BMRSSystemData.php?pT=DDAD&zT=N&dT=NRT"

Set ieApp = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
ieApp.Visible = True
ieApp.Navigate URL

While ieApp.Busy
    'wait...
Wend

Set ieDoc = ieApp.Document
For Each ele In ieApp.Document.getElementsByTagname("span")

    If ele.innerHTML = "CSV" Then
        DoEvents
        ele.Click
        'At this point you need to Save the document manually
        ' or figure out for yourself how to automate this interaction.
    End If
Next

ieApp.Quit
End Sub
```

I do not know how to automate this "Save" interaction, although I am 100% certain it can be done, I'm simply not inclined to spend my time learning how to do it for you.

Comment: it is a good starting, I found the way to save it all I need to do is to figure out how to insert the file name.

Comment: If you have already automated the "Save" assuming you know the filename & path, you can use `Name` method to rename the file, e.g., `Name "C:\myfile.csv" As "C:\Desktop\NewFile.csv"`.  This operation renames/moves the file from one location to another.

Comment: How did you automate the "Save"?

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to download any CSV from that link, the site appears to be returning an error. However the XML downloads, so there is data there. I think the problem may be on the website.

You can use the QueryTables method of the URL of the CSV file is known (or can be derived).  The URL you provide yields "No Data To Display" and an error message "There was an error calling the Web Service"

Pretty much all of this is from recording a macro using QueryTables, excep a manually input string for `fullURL` and some rudimentary error-handling.

```
Private Sub OpenURL()
'Opens the URL and splits the CSV data in to cells.
Dim fullURL as String '< - variable to contain the URL of the CSV you are attempting to download

'Example URL for CSV download from Yahoo Finance, modify as needed.
fullURL = "http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=GM&a=10&b=18&c=2010&d=06&e=27&f=2012&g=d&ignore=.csv"


'This opens the webpage
On Error GoTo ErrOpenURL
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    "URL;" & fullURL, Destination:=Range("A1"))
    .Name = fullURL
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = True
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .WebSelectionType = xlEntirePage
    .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingAll
    .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
    .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
    .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
    .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
    .WebDisableRedirections = False
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With

ExitOpenURL:
Exit Sub 'if all goes well, you can exit

'Error handling...

ErrOpenURL:
Err.Clear
MsgBox "The URL you are attempting to access cannot be opened.",vbCritical
Resume ExitOpenURL


End Sub
```

Comment: impossible with web query :(

Comment: OK. You're going to automate the button click. I have never done this before but I think I can figure it out. Will post revision later.